# Angular Material stops rendering while opening

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code:

some page HTML (MyContractsComponent.html):

```
<mat-accordion>
  <div class="page-header margin-top">
    <button
      (click)="openContractCreationDialog()">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      <span class="button-text">asd</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</mat-accordion>
```

component code:

```
  openContractCreationDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContractCreatorDialogComponent, {});;
  }
```

ContractCreatorDialogComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contract-creator-dialog',
  template: `
    <h3 class="title"  mat-dialog-title>
      <mat-icon class="middle">keyboard_backspace</mat-icon>
    </h3>
  `,
})
export class ContractCreatorDialogComponent  {

  constructor(
  ) {}
  
}
```

If I press F5, then I click on the button, and I can see this opening up:  [image]

If I press any button on the page, it changes:
[image]

So it seems that the app has stopped rendering for some reason in the middle of the icon name(?).

I can also make it work if I navigate to other pages, and come back (within the app) and click on the button again.

I have tried to exclude everything, my components are stripped from every logic, even CSS, and I cannot find out what is the root cause of the problem.  Both components are in the same module, and I us Angular Material.

MY console is empty, versions from `package.json`:

```
    "@angular/animations": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/material-luxon-adapter": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~15.0.3",
    "@jsier/retrier": "^1.2.4",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.8",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "cypress": "^12.0.2",
    "cypress-keycloak-commands": "^1.2.0",
    "iban": "0.0.14",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^19.0.3",
    "luxon": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-cacheable": "^1.4.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.6.0",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  }
```

**Update:**
It's might be interesting: I have created a `ngOnInit` hook in the component opened by the modal service, and WHEN the rendering stops, the `onInit` function won't get called at all. If I press any button, the rendering continues and the `onInit` function will trigger as well.

**Update 2:**
after upgrading to angular 15, the problem ceased to exist. Maybe the core lib, but more probably, one of our dependencies caused the bug.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors ?

Comment: no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to Angular 16, the problem ceased to exist. Probably one of our dependencies, or maybe the core lib caused the bug in an older version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import the `MatDialogModule` inside the Module that declares both `MyContractsComponent` and `ContractCreatorDialogComponent`.

Comment: it is already sadly :(

Answer (score 1):

From the code supplied I can re-create the opening of the dialog but just not sure of what you are trying to achieve. Is their more code we can't see?

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
 import { ContractCreatorDialogComponent } from '../contract-creator- 
 dialog/contract-creator-dialog.component';


 @Component({
    selector: 'app-my-contacts',
    templateUrl: './my-contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-contacts.component.css']
    })
 export class MyContactsComponent {
      constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }
 openContractCreationDialog() {
      this.dialog.open(ContractCreatorDialogComponent, {});;
  }
}
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: sadly I am unable to provide the whole application, but somewhere we have something blocking / stopping the whole rendering. What you show is the result I would expect, but I don't reach that state. I am looking for ideas or any lead where to find anything which stops this modal window rendering process.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is a button inside a mat-accordion element from the Angular Material library. When the button is clicked, it will call the openContractCreationDialog method, which you will need to implement in your component's class.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ContractCreatorDialogComponent } from './contract-creator-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
    <mat-accordion>
      <div class="page-header margin-top">
        <button
          (click)="openDialog()">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
          <span class="button-text">asd</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </mat-accordion>
  `,
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openContractCreationDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContractCreatorDialogComponent, {
      width: '450px'
    });
  }
}
```

In this example, the changeDetection property of the component is set to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. This tells Angular to run change detection on this component only when an input property changes or an event is emitted by an asynchronous pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, the problem is still present with adding the changeDetection strategy to the modal component.